# Onclick text change then display image jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I spent few hours in this particular code but seems not working for me . Basically i was trying to onclick the button then change text from 签到 to 签到成功 with the condition of if 签到成功 then display image else set the image to display:none .

Can you try to help me with this code , Thanks you .

**HTML  :**

```
<div class="checkLevel" id="damonkEYkEY">
    <span data-bind="css: safeLevelClass"> </span>
    <a href="#" id="checkLevelBtn">签到</a> 
    <img src="images/Calendartest.png" alt="" class="calendarshow" style="display:none">
</div>
```

**jQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#damonkEYkEY").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".checkLevel a").text(function(i, t) {
          return t == '签到' ? '签到成功' : '签到';

        });
        if($(".checkLevel a").text('签到成功')){
         $(".calendarshow").css("display", "block");}
        else{
         $(".calendarshow").css("display", "none");}
      }
  });
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.calendarshow { 
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: -180px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 118px;
}
```

Comment: change `if($(".checkLevel a").text('签到成功')){` to `if($(".checkLevel a").text() == '签到成功'){`

Comment: @guradio Hi , i had amend the code but the button unable to click anymore , Kindly advise

Comment: button unable to click?can you create a snippet?

Comment: @guradio i encounter an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a redundant closing curly bracket in your code. So removed it and replace `if($(".checkLevel a").text('签到成功')){`  with `if($(".checkLevel a").text()=='签到成功'){`.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#damonkEYkEY").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".checkLevel a").text(function(i, t) {
      return t == '签到' ? '签到成功' : '签到';

    });

    if($(".checkLevel a").text()=='签到成功'){
      $(".calendarshow").css("display", "block");}
    else{
      $(".calendarshow").css("display", "none");}
  });
});
```

```css
.calendarshow { 
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -180px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 118px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkLevel" id="damonkEYkEY">
  <span data-bind="css: safeLevelClass"> </span>
  <a href="#" id="checkLevelBtn">签到</a> 
  <img src="images/Calendartest.png" alt="" class="calendarshow" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Comment: Great. I am happy that I can helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#damonkEYkEY").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".checkLevel a").text(function(i, t) {
       return t == '签到' ? '签到成功' : '签到';

     });

     if ($(".checkLevel a").text() == '签到成功') {
       $(".calendarshow").css("display", "block");
     } else {
       $(".calendarshow").css("display", "none");
     }

   });
 });
```

```css
.calendarshow {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -180px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 118px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkLevel" id="damonkEYkEY">
  <span data-bind="css: safeLevelClass"> </span>
  <a href="#" id="checkLevelBtn">签到</a> 
  <img src="images/Calendartest.png" alt="" class="calendarshow" style="display:none">
</div>
```

You have extra `}`

Comment: Hi guradio , ya that was my mistake , noted on this . Thanks for your remind :)

Comment: glad to help mate :)